# Error: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, objectdatasource

I use asp.net and EF 4 in C#.

I have a DetailsView with associated a `ObjectDataSource`.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="uxEntityDataSourceAuthors" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetAuthors" 
        TypeName="WebProject.Web.Cms.AdminCms.Sections.CmsContents.ContentInformation">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

This the code for the Method:

---

```
    public IEnumerable<CmsAuthor> GetAuthors()
    {
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole("CMS-AUTHOR"))
    {
    using (CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel context = new CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel())
    {
                            // Display all Authors for specific logged-in User.
                            // Get Guid for current logged-in User.
                            MembershipUser myLoggedinUser = Membership.GetUser();
                            Guid myUserGuid = (Guid)myLoggedinUser.ProviderUserKey;
                            // Get list of Authors filtering my current logged-in User.
                            var myAuthorsForAuthor = from a in context.CmsAuthors
                                                     where a.UserId == myUserGuid
                                                     orderby a.LastName ascending
                                                     select a;
                            return myAuthorsForAuthor.AsEnumerable();
                        }
                    }
                    return null;  
 }
```

---

When I'm running the code I receive this error:

```
 The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're closing the `CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel` called `context` before getting the data. Remember that `AsEnumerable()` will return a *lazy* enumerator, no data has been read from the source when you return and dispose of `context.

Use `ToArray()` (or `ToList()`) to ensure you get the data into memory before closing the source.

Comment: The list and array methods are called ToList() and ToArray() respectively

Comment: Hi, Id do not have AsArray() (or AsList()) only ToList().

Answer (score 2):

Calling AsEnumerable does not enumerate the collection it just changes it from `IQeuryable<T>` to `IEnumerble<T>`.  You are disposing of the ObjectContext before the data is fetched from the database.  Use `ToList()` which will enumerate the collection and fetch the data.